# in PHPUnit how to force tearDownAfterClass() to run in case of unexpected exceptions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

So every time I encounter unexpected exceptions in PHPUnit (such as fails to insert into db because of an integrity check) my tests fail and it errors out without running `tearDownAfterClass()` function. This will leave my database in a messy state so I have to manually go and clean it up. Is there a way to ensure `tearDownAfterClass()` is always executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHPUnit will call `tearDownAfterClass` even when there are errors and failures in test methods. It will *not* call it when `setUpBeforeClass` throws an exception. In order to ensure that your database is cleaned up, move the cleanup code into a new method that you call from `tearDownAfterClass` and the catch clause in `setUpBeforeClass`.

```
function FooTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    static function setUpBeforeClass() {
        try {
            ... setup code that might fail ...
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            self::cleanupDatabase();
            throw $e;  // so the tests will be skipped
        }
    }

    static function tearDownAfterClass() {
        self::cleanupDatabase();
    }

    static function cleanupDatabase() {
        ... clean ...
    }

    ... test methods ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the function

```
protected function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e)
```

with for instance;

```
$this->tearDownAfterClass();
throw $e;
```

Comment: **Warning:** This will call `tearDownAfterClass` for every test method that fails or errors--not once at the end for the entire class.

Comment: -1 It also doesn't solve the problem because `onNotSuccessfulTest` isn't called when `setUpBeforeClass` throws an exception.